# Cannot build open-source project

Tags: macos, go, build

I'd like to contribute to an OSS project built with `go`, but I'm having hard time compiling it. It looks as if I'm missing something obvious.

I think the problem is related to how `go` is installed on my computer, and not to the project itself, thus I'm posting it here on StackOverflow, instead of project's "Issues" section.

Below is what I'm doing.

1. I've installed [`go`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/go.rb) using `homebrew`:

   ```
   $ brew install go
   Updating Homebrew...
   ==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
   Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
   ==> Updated Formulae
   libebml

   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/go-1.8.3.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
   Already downloaded: /Users/gmile/Library/Caches/Homebrew/go-1.8.3.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
   ==> Pouring go-1.8.3.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
   ==> Caveats
   A valid GOPATH is required to use the `go get` command.
   If $GOPATH is not specified, $HOME/go will be used by default:
     https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

   You may wish to add the GOROOT-based install location to your PATH:
     export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
   ==> Summary
     /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3: 7,035 files, 282.0MB
   $
   ```
2. Then I cloned the repo:

   ```
   $ hub clone lucapette/fakedata
   ```
3. I ran `make setup` (per instruction), which at first did not complete successfully:

   ```
   $ make setup
   go get -u github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
   gometalinter --install
   make: gometalinter: No such file or directory
   make: *** [setup] Error 1
   $
   ```

   I figured that is because `gometalinter` is nowhere in my `$PATH`, so have added it (I'm using [fish-shell](http://fishshell.com)):

   ```
   $ set fish_user_paths /Users/gmile/go/bin
   ```
4. running `make setup` seem to have succeeded now. This is the output:

   ```
   $ make setup
   go get -u github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
   gometalinter --install
   Installing:
     aligncheck
     deadcode
     dupl
     errcheck
     gas
     goconst
     gocyclo
     goimports
     golint
     gosimple
     gotype
     ineffassign
     interfacer
     lll
     megacheck
     misspell
     safesql
     staticcheck
     structcheck
     unconvert
     unparam
     unused
     varcheck
   $
   ```
5. **Running `make build` fails**:

   ```
   $ make build
   go build
   main.go:11:2: cannot find package"github.com/lucapette/fakedata/pkg/fakedata" in any of:
           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/lucapette/fakedata/pkg/fakedata (from $GOROOT)
           /Users/gmile/go/src/github.com/lucapette/fakedata/pkg/fakedata (from $GOPATH)
   main.go:12:2: cannot find package "github.com/spf13/pflag" in any of:
           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/spf13/pflag (from $GOROOT)
           /Users/gmile/go/src/github.com/spf13/pflag (from $GOPATH)
   make: *** [build] Error 1
   $
   ```

So either [Contributing](https://github.com/lucapette/fakedata/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) guideline is incomplete, or I'm missing something obvious about installing and managing go packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path when cloning the source must be on the golang PATH like : 
`/home/gujarat/golang/src/github.com/lucapette/fakedata`

as you can see my Path to golang path is : `/home/gujarat/golang/`.
You can also print your golang path in your terminal by entering : `$GOPATH`.

And the `git clone` should be in the following the exact as above path : `src/github.com/lucapette/`.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/
mkdir lucaptte
cd lucapette
git clone https://github.com/lucapette/fakedata.git
```

When you are running the `make` command which trigger `go build` this command will look the `$GOPATH` and your `$GOROOT` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your go source should in your gopath - here it is Users/gmile/src. Use go get to fetch the pkg you want to work on instead and it should work.